# SSRS Lookup on single dataset

Tags: sql, reporting-services, lookup, ssrs-tablix

Hopefully you can help!

I have a single data source in my SSRS report. With this data source, I have populated a tablix. The tablix looks something like this:

```
SalesPerson  ID  Group   Sales
Sarah        1   1       1234
Ross         2   1       555
Gemma        3   2       678
Jill         4   2       345
Jack         5   3       987
Peter        6   2       432
Henry        7   2       356
```

The report is set up to create a different page for each of the sales people. for example, on the first page of the report, only first record would be shown (the record that holds Sarah's information, the second page would show the record for Ross' information ,etc..)

The issues I face is this:

At the bottom of the report, I need to include a textbox that displays the group number that the specific employee belongs to (the employee who is currently being displayed on the page).

I think that I need to do some sort of lookup on the IDReportItem to return the group ID in order to do this, but have had no luck in my attempts.

I understand that this is a horrible way of doing things, but I am limited to using this single dataset for performing this task.

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated,

Thanks you!

Comment: What limits you to using a single dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in a single textbox, but you can do it with a second tablix that uses the same dataset.

Create your second tablix and position it at the bottom of the page, then set your grouping to be the same on both tablixes and use the second tablix to only display the group ID, plus whatever label you want.

Create a new row group for each tablix (grouping on group ID), then right click the group and browse to `Group Properties -> Page Breaks` and check the box that says "Between each instance of a group". Do this for both tablixes.

Answer (score 2):

This is what grouping is designed for. Build your table, and set the page break attribute to true.

You can have multiple rows under your group. Since your group is a field, simply add it to the detail row.

Answer (score 0):

Your grouping is obviously set up right to get the report paging correctly.

You could add a **List** to the report, set the grouping on that (with page break between groups)

Inside the list - Add a RECTANGLE.  (this be important!)

Once you've *added the rectangle*, you can add another as many objects as you like.  In your case I think that may be a matrix and a text box

eg

[image]

Then it just becomes as spacing issue (to get the page looking right)